# Joomla 3 with k2 sef url issue

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, sef, jroute

I have an issue with k2 sef settings. I want all items to have no category structure, example:

```
http://example.com/cat1/cat2/item1 -> http://example.com/item1
```

I found the setting: Prefix for item URLs and it is set to no.

But it still shows the category structure, also i noticed that modules in the item page showing related items have an issue: If I am in the page

```
http://example.com/cat1/cat2/item1
```

showning an item from cat3 the link will still be

```
http://example.com/cat1/cat2/item1
```

and the item also works under the wrong category. I suspect something being wrong with Jroute functionality.

I'm updating this site from 1.5 to Joomla 3 with all newest versions of CMS and extensions.

Any guidance in troubleshooting this issue is highly appriciated!

Gr,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing sh404sef wich did the job out of the box, I think the updating caused some db tables to be corrupted..

Thx for the help all!

Answer (score 1):

Disable SEF, and check the Itemid to find which K2 feature is answering the request

From my experience, to avoid *cat* levels, you have to define **a menu item for each article** "Item" (Create a menu item linking directly to an item in K2).

*There is no standard way to define all SEF articles to K2 single item feature.*

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best way to remove categories from your URL, both for K2 and regular Joomla articles, is to use a third-party SEO extension. There are many available at the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/site-management/sef), both free and paid.

Personally I often use [sh404sef](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/sh404sef) (paid extension), but I just noticed the free "[Direct Alias](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/direct-alias)" plugin that seems to be able to do exactly what you want: remove categories and menu aliases, and leave you with a simple url like "http://example.com/item1".